# Sentence structure: As ... as ... is, ... could be even worse / better / more

Tags: meaning, sentence, argument-structure

Tell me the meaning & structure of the sentence.

Normally *as ... adj/adv ... as* is used for comparison between two items, *as cool as a cucumber*.

- *As dangerous a threat as North Korea is*, some analysts believe that were a junta suddenly to gain power, it could be even more unpredictable and bellicose than it is under the current leadership.

Comment: "As light as a Nancy is in her movements, his friends believe that were Amy to even try her terpsichorean skills, she would far outstrip Nancy."  (While X being the case, Y could be more pronounced in its effects). That roughly is the meaning.

Comment: As cool as a cucumber is, an ice lolly is cooler.

Answer (score -1):

Stockfish is correct but incomplete. I add that the construct implies that we are to see X as part of a range of possibilities. “As bad as things are, they could be worse.” The sentence suggests that things are already bad rather than good; it also points to the possibility that there are even worse prospects (Y).

Comment: In my (albeit limited) experience, the addition is not superfluous. In almost all cases the construct invites the reader, or hearer, to recognise that X lies on a scale of some sort, and that Y lies further along the scale. Good as my riposte is, it could be better.